# Find first match in two tables

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I've got two tables (Amortization (A) and Compounding (C)) and I'm trying to find the first Date<sub>A</sub> where Date<sub>A</sub> > Date<sub>C</sub> AND Value<sub>A</sub> < Value<sub>C</sub>.  I assume it'll be something like Index(Date<sub>A</sub>,Match(And()), but I'm not entirely certain what the matches would be.  So, given the below tables, the returned value would be 2/1/2044 (Date<sub>A</sub> = 1/31/2044<2/1/2044 AND $38,185.18>$37,767.32).

```
        Compounding                     Amortization
 Value          Date              Value          Date
 $37,894.51    11/22/2043         $41,751.75    11/1/2043
 $37,952.62    12/6/2043          $40,428.16    12/1/2043
 $38,010.74    12/20/2043         $39,100.03    1/1/2044
 $38,068.88    1/3/2044           $37,767.32    2/1/2044
 $38,127.02    1/17/2044          $36,430.04    3/1/2044
 $38,185.18    1/31/2044          $35,088.16    4/1/2044
 $38,243.35    2/14/2044          $33,741.67    5/1/2044
 $38,301.53    2/28/2044          
 $38,359.73    3/13/2044
```

Edit 6/30: Updated example data to more closely reflect actual scenario

Answer (score 1):

Maybe, assuming above are in ColumnA:D, please try selecting those columns and: Format - Conditional formatting..., **Custom formula is** and:

```
=AND($C1-$A1>0,$C2-$A2<0)
```

with yellow fill. <kbd>Done</kbd>.

Adjust the Applies to range to A2:D8, assuming that is where `5/1/2044` resides.

Note (may be very relevant) above ignores the dates and relies purely on when the value column `Amortisation` drops below that for `Compounding`.

Comment: Thanks for the attempt, but this doesn't meet half the requirements.  I want to return just the first valid overlap date to a cell, not highlight any entries in which the condition is true.

Answer (score 0):

Array (CSE) formula:

```
=INDEX(D:D,MATCH(1,(D:D>B:B)*(C:C<A:A),0))
```

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>    <kbd>Shift</kbd>    <kbd>Enter</kbd>

Comment: That works perfectly on the sample set, however when applied to the full set it returns unexpected values. In the full set, I'm applying via named ranges across two different sheets, which Name Manager show as being correct. [Full Set Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/c19de373dsqr9x5/DateFind.xlsx?dl=0)

Comment: @flipinho2005 I don't see why it would stop working with the reasons you mention. What are the involved columns relatively to the sample? I suppose they are in different sheets and you didn't forget to prefix the ranges with the sheet names, right?

Comment: The sample set is a subset of Compounding!J:K and Amortization!L:M.  Name Manager has the named ranges as absolute column references with sheet name.  I'm actually attempting the lookup 4 times, given 2 sets each of C and A, none of which return the expected value (notated in Compounding!$H8:$H11).  As far as the sample subset goes:


    Date<sub>A</sub>  = Amortization!$M:$M = ActualDateA
    Value<sub>A</sub> = Amortization!$L:$L = ActualValueA
    Date<sub>C</sub>  = Compounding!$K:$K  = ActualDateC
    Value<sub>C</sub> = Compounding!$J:$J  = ActualValueC

Comment: Dont worry for the subscript formating, but I would like to see the actual formula that you tried, so I might be able to help. can you post it? (surround by ` ) or is it present somewhere in the workbook that you shared so I can see it?

Comment: Notice that comparison expressions must be parenthesized, because the `*` operator has precedence over comparison ones.

Comment: Also beware that the arrays in array formulas MUST be aligned (same size). It might be that your named ranges dont verify this property.

Comment: Array formulas don't need to be the same size (added a new sheet - Demo - demonstrating).  I think I found the issue though in setting up that demonstration.  The formula is doing a straight comparison of DateA[n]:DateC[n].  This is an issue as A is biweekly and C is monthly.  

If you look at Demo!A:F, the expected value is returned because DateA[8]>DateC[8] and ValueA[8]<ValueC[8].  In Demo!H:M, you receive the incorrect value because where ValueA[8]<ValueC[8] DateA[8]!>DateC[8].  However, if you blank pad DateA and ValueA to where DateA[8]>DateC[8] you get the correct value as in Demo!O:T

Comment: Interestingly enough, if you change the date formula to >= it returns 1/1/1900.

I'm wondering if the only way to work around this is to treat the arrays as such in VBA and just parse each DateC [as n], find the first C row where DateA >= n and check for ValueC < Valuen.

BTW, production formulas are in Compounding!$G8:11.